# android all BottomNavigationView items have same color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

Below is my BottomNavigationView code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="#291D1E"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:currentTab=""
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

And my colorstate drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item  android:color="#FF4D14" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:color="#532322" />
</selector>
```

But I am getting following output:

SCREENSHOT
[image: Screenshot]

**How do I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Modify Color_State_Drawable.xml and modify this line :-

```
<Item android:color="#532322" />
```

To

```
<item android:color="#532322" android_state_checked="false" />
```